# Tag Cloud - How To Show All Tags In A Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of categories. When you click on a category lets say Computers it should only show a tag cloud of the items in that category in this case Computers. Tags from the Mobile Phone category should not be showing.

Currently my tag cloud shows all tags across all categories.

Im using the Acts_as_tagable_gem https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

**How would someone go about showing only the tags inside that category?**

Here is my view. **Please refer to tag_cloud**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class = "col-md-3">
    <h1>
      <strong><%= @category.name %></strong>
    </h1>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-9">
    <div id="tag_cloud">
      <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w[s m l]) do |tag, css_class| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name, id: @category.id), class: css_class %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div id="items" class="transitions-enabled">
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
            <div class="box panel panel-default">
              <div class="itemlisttitle"><%= item.title %></div>    
            <%= link_to image_tag(item.image.url (:medium)), item %>
              <div class ="panel-body">
              <div class = "itemlistprice">$<%= item.price %></div>
              <div class = "itemlistretailer"><%= image_tag item.user.avatar(:thumb) %> Retailer: <%= link_to item.user.username, item.user %></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes **Please refer to the last line**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :categories

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'

  resources :users
  get 'user_items'  => 'users#show_user_items'
  root 'items#home'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'show'  => 'users#show'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :items
  get 'items_new' => 'items#new'


  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'categories#show', as: :tag
```

Category Controller Show Action.

```
  def show
    @tags = Item.tag_counts_on(:tags)
    if params[:tag]
      @items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```

Comment: It looks like (in your controller) the definition of `@tags` doesn't care what `@category` has been set to.  Maybe you need to switch your `show` action logic around a bit so `@tags` is set last?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Hello. I posted the answer. What do you think? Do you know  a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.

If anyone knows a better way please post. Thanks!

in my show action put

```
  def show
    @tags = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).tag_counts_on(:tags)
    if params[:tag]
      @items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```